# NullReferenceException, VB.Net Page_load Method

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, nullreferenceexception

Stack Trace:

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
**StartupMilestones.Site.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\StartupMilestones\StartupMilestones\Site.Master.vb:8**
System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +91
System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +74
System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +146
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, _
    Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2207
```

I can't seem to figure out why I'm getting a NullReferenceException on this. Here's the only code I have in for Site.Master.vb as of now:

```
Public Class Site
 Inherits System.Web.UI.MasterPage


 Public Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles 
  Me.Load
    Dim lbluserid As New Label
    lbluserid.Text = "YO!"

 End Sub
End Class
```

What's weird is that the Stack Trace is referencing line 8 at this location: `**C:\inetpub\wwwroot\StartupMilestones\StartupMilestones\Site.Master.vb:8**` while the file in VS shows `C:\Working Projects\StartUpMilestones\DEV\Site.Master.vb` in the Properties window. What's amiss? Thanks!

Comment: What does the code for `Page_Load` look like in the file at `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\StartupMilestones\StartupMilestones\Site.Master.vb` on line 8?

Comment: @KarlAnderson, that's t2he thing. I have nothing there. That location does not exist on my machine. Granted, someone did hand this off to me and so I'm trying to get it to run here and can't figure out why there's anything pointing to a location that doesn't exist? Is it pulling information from the previous developer's machine and, if so, what is storing these locations? 

THanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the physical location that your virtual directory in IIS is using, like this:

For IIS7:

1. Open IIS Manager. For information about opening IIS Manager, see Open IIS Manager (IIS 7).
2. In the Connections pane, expand the Sites node in the tree, and then click to select the site in which you want to change the physical path for virtual directory content.
3. In the Actions pane, click View Virtual Directories.
4. From the Virtual Directories page, select a virtual directory in the list.
5. In the Actions pane, click Basic Settings.
6. In the Physical path box, change the path of the virtual directory content.
7. Click OK.

For more information read [Change the Physical Path of Virtual Directory Content (IIS 7)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754640%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).